# VBA /ADODB recordset is not cleared - PC dependent

Tags: vba, ado

As usual, a bit of a strange problem with one of my Excel VBA macro's.

I use Excel as a database, with one worksheet storing a large amount of data.
I search the date using ADODB.

Everything run's fine on most PC's, but today, one of my colleagues encountered a problem which I cannot understand.
The issue is only seen on his computer. He sent me the file, I failed to reproduce the issue on my PC. Additionally, other colleagues using the same source code do not have any issues.

**The issue:**
One of the fields (column) in the database is the "case status". When we change the status of a case from 'Open' to 'Closed' and then query all records with status 'Open', the changed case still shows up in the resulting record set. When I verify the status in the worksheet which is used as the query source, I can see that the status is set to 'Closed' but ADODB still find it as 'Open'.

As I mentioned, this happens only on 1 PC, so it cannot be the code. Could this be a particular library and if so, which one. I compared the used libraries via a teamviewer session on his and my PC and they are all identical.

I am lost.

This is the code I use

```
Public Sub OpenDB()
If cnn.state = adStateOpen Then cnn.Close
cnn.ConnectionString = "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};DBQ=" & _
ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & ActiveWorkbook.Name
cnn.Open
End Sub

Public Sub closeRS()
If rs.state = adStateOpen Then rs.Close
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
End Sub

...
If PRODUCTname <> "" Or PIRstate <> "" Or cmbPIRnr.Text <> "" Then
'now extract data
closeRS
OpenDB
    
rs.Open strSQL, cnn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
  'Now putting the data on the sheet
  ActiveCell.CopyFromRecordset rs
Else
  MsgBox "I was not able to find any matching records.", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly
  Exit Sub
End If
...
```

[image: libraries used in this workbook]

Comment: Do you save the workbook after making the change and before running the query?  FYI posts with no code tend to get closed pretty quickly here, so you might consider adding your VBA.

Comment: The code I am using is pretty standard, but I will add this to the post. I am not saving the workbook but one observation I made was that on the PC where the issue occurs, when saving the file, it shows an error about the file being in use by another user.

Comment: I would try to resolve the Save issue first...